# Find "curve + straight + curve" path

Tags: algorithm

[image]

I'm trying to calculate a path from Start point (T-like black shape) with Start direction (green) to Finish point with finish direction in 2D space. The whole path (light blue) is a bunch of points. I need to find positions of two red points. The problem is that in most cases circle sections (I and III purple) has not equal amount of points i.e. different length. Start and finish directions can be any from 0 to 359 degrees.

Comment: I tried to calculate sections I and III simultaneously until direction from last point of section I is approximately 180 degrees rotated direction from last point of section III but did find out that amount of points in I and III is different so one direction is never reversed to another.

Comment: Also I tried to calculate all points of finish circle first and then calculate points and direction of the Start circle. The result is direction from first point of start circle is already reversed to some direction of some point from finish circle.

Comment: It seems that, you want to find a straight line tangent to two circles, but you haven't tackled this problem directly. why?

Comment: @fana cause I know nothing.

Comment: *"The problem is that in most cases circle sections (I and III purple) has not equal amount of points"*: finding the coordinates of the red points is a purely mathematical problem and is not related to the number of points you generate in your code. If your question is about finding the coordinates of the red points, then all the story around it about finding the blue path, the given start and finish points and their directions,... is irrelevant. All you need to know is C1, C2 and the radius of these circles.

Comment: @trincot "All you need to know is C1, C2 and the radius of these circles" - I know that but still I am here. Guess there is something more to know. Maybe I need to know how to find direct common tangent of two circles.

Comment: When C1 and C2 is center location of each circle...
Let P1 is the red point on the circle that center is C1.
C1 to P1 directional component of the vector (C1 - C2) is difference of radius.
From this relation, you can calculate the angle between the two directions (C1 to P1) and ( C1 to C2 ).
(2 values sutisfy the relation,  you should select one side based on your usage.)

Comment: (Just in case : ) Directional component can be calculated with inner-product, and inner-product(a,b) equals `|a|*|b|*cos(theta)`, where theta is the angle between 2 vectors (a and b).
Here, with this equation, you can get the value of `cos(theta)`.

Comment: @fana this is helpfull. how do i like this? you could make it as answer if you want some rating points.

Comment: Posted as answer with a figure.

Comment: If you're looking for the shortest trajectory connecting a particular start point/direction with a particular end point/direction, with a limit on the turning radius, you're looking for a [Dubins path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubins_path). You'll find plenty of example code out there to calculate Dubins paths.

Comment: @Sneftel oh my goodness thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this a programming question, here is an implementation for getting the two tangent points (the red points).

This implementation defines Vector and Circle classes, each with methods to create new results from them. The Circle class has a `tangentWith` method, which takes another circle as argument and returns an array with two Vectors, i.e. the coordinates of the two red points.

The snippet below is interactive. It starts with the initial two circles, as depicted in your question, but allows you to draw alternative circles using the mouse (click to determine center of circle, and drag to set its radius):

```js
class Vector {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        // Derive polar coordinates:
        this.size = (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 0.5;
        this.angle = Math.atan2(this.y, this.x);
    }
    subtract(v) {
        return new Vector(this.x - v.x, this.y - v.y);
    }
    add(v) {
        return new Vector(this.x + v.x, this.y + v.y);
    }
    multiplyBy(scalar) {
        return new Vector(this.x * scalar, this.y * scalar);
    }
    resize(size) {
        return this.multiplyBy(size / this.size);
    }
    rotate(angle) {
        angle += this.angle;
        return new Vector(this.size * Math.cos(angle), this.size * Math.sin(angle));
    }
}

class Circle extends Vector {
    constructor(x=0, y=0, radius=0) {
        super(x, y);
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    touch(v) { // Set radius so that v is on the circle
        return Circle.fromVector(this, this.subtract(v).size);
    }
    tangentWith(other) { // Main algorithm
        let v = this.subtract(other);
        const sinus = (this.radius - other.radius) / v.size;
        if (Math.abs(sinus) > 1) return []; // One circle includes the other: no tangent
        v = v.rotate(Math.asin(sinus) + Math.PI / 2);
        return [v.resize(this.radius).add(this), v.resize(other.radius).add(other)];
    }
    static fromVector(v, radius=0) {
        return new Circle(v.x, v.y, radius);
    }
}

// The circles as depicted in the question
const circles = [new Circle(50, 50, 25), new Circle(80, 120, 25)];

// I/O management, allowing to draw different circles
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function mouseVector(e) {
    return new Vector(e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
    circles.reverse()[0] = Circle.fromVector(mouseVector(e));
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
    if (!e.buttons) return;
    circles[0] = circles[0].touch(mouseVector(e));
    draw();
});

function drawCircle(c) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawSegment(start, end) {
    if (!start) return;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
    ctx.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    circles.map(drawCircle);
    drawSegment(...circles[0].tangentWith(circles[1]));
}
draw();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
First draw C1, then C2 (use mouse drag)<br>
<canvas width="600" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: wow this is great!

Answer (score 1):

I drawn a simple figure:

[image]

As you see, red line directional component of the vector (**C1** - **C2**) or (**C2** - **C1**) equals difference of radius.
(Roughly) writing this relation as a equation,

- Inner-Product( **C1** -**C2**, **U** ) = dr
- dr = | r1 - r2 |

where **U** is unit vector has direction along the red line, and 2 scalars {r1, r2} are circle radius.
This becomes to:

| **C1** - **C2** | * | **U** | * cos(theta) = | **C1** - **C2** | * 1 * cos(theta) = dr

where theta is the angle between (**C1**-**C2**) and **U**.
Now you can calculate the `cos(theta)` value as:

cos(theta) = dr / | **C1**-**C2** |

Comment: As mentioned in my comment, the answer is not only one.
(e.g. in my figure, P1 and P2 can be on left hand side.)

Comment: What "(Roughly)" means is about this point. Equations are not accurate in this regard.

Comment: Please forgive my bad mathematical writing.
But I think I was able to explain the way to solve the problem.

Comment: now worries you are great. thank you kindly.